# Why would you use a union with only one member type in XML Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I found a type defined this way in the Office Open XML spec.

```
<xsd:simpleType name="ST_TextBulletSize">
  <xsd:union memberTypes="ST_TextBulletSizePercent"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="ST_TextBulletSizePercent">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:pattern value="0*((2[5-9])|([3-9][0-9])|([1-3][0-9][0-9])|400)%"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the creators of the OOXML schema did it that way, no one but they can tell us.  But I imagine you're asking for speculation, not authoritative answers.  Reasons I can imagine:

- There used to be three member types, but two of them went away as the design of the schema changed.
- The designers think that this is the kind of place where the next version might want multiple kinds of ST_TextBulletSize (percent, absolute, degrees Kelvin, magnum, derringer, ...) so they have prepared the way by making it a union type now, even though there's only one member.  (It's like writing `begin` ... `end` or `{` ... `}` around the then- or else-clause of a conditional in Pascal or C even when it contains only a single statement: you don't need to do it, but when you don't, you are likely to forget to add it when you change that one statement to a sequence of statements, and that leads to trouble.)
- The guy who wrote this just wondered what error message the validator would throw if a union just had one type, and then forgot to change it to something that would be less eccentric.

Comment: So it doesn't do anything special. Thanks!

Comment: Correct; it doesn't do anything special.